# How to filter out the TreeNodes(grandchildren level) from treeviewer using Viewfilter in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, swt

How to filter out the Tree Nodes (grandchildren level) from tree viewer using View filter in SWT.I want to filter out the grand children node from the treeviewer.

Answer (score 0):

You just can filter your items in Container.

```
ArrayList<Nodes> nodeList;
```

Then add container to treeView;

Answer (score 0):

The Logic would be filter children in ContentProvider for the tree view